# How to import library module in android application

Tags: android, data-binding, sdk, android-databinding, aar

I have created a new Android project, created a library module and put my library project in module. Then, I imported the module in `build.gradle` of new Android project. When I run the app, I am getting the following errors.

Found data binding errors.

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:text' with parameter type java.lang.String on
>   com.example.consumer.app.widget.CustomLabel.
>   file:E:\GitProjects\Android\SDK
>   App\mylibrary\src\main\res\layout\alert_dialog.xml loc:49:28 - 49:62
>   ****\ data binding error ****
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on
>   com.example.consumer.app.widget.CustomEditText.
>   file:E:\GitProjects\Android\SDK
>   App\mylibrary\src\main\res\layout\fragment_otp_verification.xml
>   loc:72:12 - 81:41
>   ****\ data binding error ****
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on
>   com.example.consumer.app.widget.CustomEditText.
>   file:E:\GitProjects\Android\SDK
>   App\mylibrary\src\main\res\layout\input_dialog.xml loc:34:12 - 39:49

Comment: how did u import it? show your gradle

Comment: Why do you think that it is an issue related to import?

Comment: This is how I imported my library project.            implementation project(path: ':mylibrary')

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because i'm new here so the errors which you are facing is because your depenedencies versions are not matching with the library version and one more thing to be sure that if you are using AndroidX then please migrate the library to AndroidX as well these can be the possiblities.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. My library versions are same in both app module and library module and I am not using AndroidX for now